# How do I back up my 100% full Macbook hard drive, format, install Windows and recover the files?

Tags: windows, backup, osx-lion, macbook, format

I want to keep everything.

I should be able to just highlight all, drag it onto an external drive and feel safe.

How can I verify that *all* my files are safely copied to the external drive?

Comment: Most of my question has been deleted. This is not my question. Its only part of it. Great. The only place I thought I could get a proper answer and I've been censored. Please try to guess the rest of my question. Thanks.

Comment: what is missing from the question you asked?  You could have put it in your comment above.

Comment: What I removed is plainly visible for anyone that clicks the [revision link](http://superuser.com/posts/463506/revisions). And it was quite a rant I removed. I see no additional questions in that part, and even if there where, you are only supposed to ask *one* question at time.

Comment: Yup, that was quite a rant.

Comment: Do you agree with it? The four questions in my actual header question should be able to be reworded so its only one question, including the deleted questions about trackpad interface still working etc, but I don't know how to rephrase it so that someone knows to give me the full details.

Comment: Irrelevant.  But since you asked I have 30 years of experience working with computers (going back to C64's, AppleII's, etc).  I switched to a Mac from Windows in 2004, and have never looked back.  Here's why:  I have certifications/job/experience, because of everyone else's down time. I teach because of downtime, and I'm published, because of downtime. So though I appreciate downtime (which in my world is my uptime), when it comes to my downtime, I choose Apple because of its uptime.  And, no.  I've never felt a Mac was a computer with non-removable training wheels.  Like I said, irrelevant.

Comment: @PaulJamesNicholson If you use Bootcamp to install Windows, part of the process installs all of the drivers for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a program like [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com) (to duplicate the drive) then use the command

```
cmp /dev/hda /dev/hdb
```

it will stop at the first differing byte, writing out its offset, or on EOF on the shorter drive.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please say that in English?

Comment: After you have run Carbon Copy Cloner (link provided), and have copied everything over to your backup location (hard drive), you need to compare the original data to the backup data (to be sure you got it all).  Go to terminal (since your using a Mac it's easy, command space drops down Spotlight, type terminal).  Once terminal opens you will type the command cmp /this/is/the/location/of/the/source /this/is/the/location/of/the/destination

Comment: Is there a reason you don't do this the easy way and install Windows in Bootcamp and not remove OS X so that you 1) know you have everything 2) Have OS X to go back to when you are ready to give up on Windows? 3) Don't have to worry about loosing any data files whatsoever?

Comment: Thanks so much. I still need to know more steps in the answer. What  format should the hard drive be? Can I do that from the Macbook onto a 1 TB USB3 external drive if the macbook contains 750 GB of data? Will windows be able to read it? After I format the internal Macbook drive (dont know how), how can I install windows? Will trackpad and other controls work properly? If windows cant make them work, can another program? Have you heard of running a windows operating system exclusively from a macbook before? Is there any difference in Mac hardware that will cause problems at any point?

Comment: "Is there a reason you don't do this the easy way and install Windows in Bootcamp and not remove OS X..." Dont know how. Hard drive is tiny - only 750 GB. My Windows desktop in storage is full with 20 TB. I like portable laptop, but not lack of hard drive space. My life is all about recording and editing in HD.

Comment: @PaulJamesNicholson - I "dual boot" Windows and Mac OS.  That is, I have A MBP with OS X installed, that also has Windows installed.  When I turn on the computer, I hold down the option key on my keyboard, and I select OS X, or Windows.  After choosing that, the one I pick boots up.  This can be achieved using Bootcamp which is built in to Mac OS.  The process to accomplish this is automated, and when you are done, you will have both on your laptop.

Comment: How do you divide such a menial amount of hard drive space?

Comment: Windows is not natively going to read the Mac file system.  You would have to buy a separate piece of software for that.  Mac's can read Windows File systems.  Maybe I can help you sort out what you are trying to accomplish by addressing the actual problem you are having, instead of trying to fix your solution?

Comment: I guess its okay that no games work on Mac. But when a dialog box opens in premiere or photoshop or dreamweaver and I want to delete, rename etc, I have to go to Finder, which doesn't even tell you the file path. Macs take ten steps what Windows can do in one. The photos and videos from my phone, the voice memos and every other thing disappear into the abyss using something called syncing. I dont like it.In fact I hate it.Everything is counter intuitive and limited. When the advanced options in a program are the choice between a pink or blue background, you know its not a computer - its a toy.

Comment: If you look at the picture I added to my answer, you'll see a Finder window.  If you look at the top of the window you can see the path of the file I selected in my Finder window /System/Library/CoreServices...
You have a problem with things "disappearing into the abyss" with a phone?  What model?  What are you syncing (causing to be the same between your phone and some other device)?

Comment: As for Mac's being limited?  Your's is the first complaint of Mac's being limited I've heard in 30+ years ;)  It is different than a Windows machine.  If you are expecting the same behavior as Windows, that isn't a problem with design in OS X.  If you don't like it I can respect that, but I think I can help point out solutions that you may not know about.  You may even be trying to do things the hard way thinking that is how you do it.  I had to change a few things when I switched to a Mac, and found it faster.

Comment: Pictures and links you have mentioned are invisible from my end, unless I need some kind of training to use this website. iPhone using itunes syncing. iphone using imovie syncing, iphoto syncing, download purchases syncing, time capsule syncing. no idea where my files are going and whats happening to them. i have put all my files into one folder since using a mac - downloads. i used to be so organised. i have lost diaries permanently that were older than 30 days because itunes decided that by default they should be deleted. credit card numbers, phone numbers, addresses. All gone. Faster? Files

Comment: It sounds like there may be a problem in configuration with syncing.  Have you contacted Apple and asked for assistance as you do have a warranty on your systems.  Second, why are you putting everything in Downloads?  On a mac you have a user with folders called Documents, Music, Movies, etc.  They are all there by default.  You can see them on the left side of the Finder picture in my answer.

Comment: As for things "disappearing" after 30 days, it appears you don't understand how iCloud works.  Try this link:  http://ipod.about.com/od/glossary/a/Icloud-Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm

Comment: For photo's/videos all iCloud does is act as a wireless bridge between your phone and your computer.  The photo's/videos stay available for 30 days, then are deleted FROM ICLOUD.  If you have saved them to your Mac, or have them on your camera roll (access it by using iPhoto or Photos on your iPhone) they will still be there.  If you sync your phone (wired/wirelessly) you likely have the photos available on your mac using iPhoto/Aperture and videos may be in iMovie.

Comment: @PaulJamesNicholson Just a friendly warning, if you think _windows_ will give you more "control over your file system", you will be sadly disappointed... And no, I do not like mac either, still prefer it to windows though.

Comment: the images and links suddenly showed up. icloud would need to take 20GB a day from me. in australia, bandwidth costs $100 per 15 GB wireless internet. I have just used time capsule to backup my hard drive. it took 8 hours. now can I delete my precious files and deal with the backup later? or will the next few backups overwrite my precious files and say 'Congratulations! We have deleted all your years of hard work! Kind Regards, Apple.'?

I have 2GB available space on my macbook and the system is crashing so i need to free up space.
Is time capsule safe? at all?

Comment: oops. i spoke too soon. the time capsule miscalculated the amount of data to be 'backed up'. i didnt want to close the lid and leave the cafe, so i sat there until 4am (there is a power point next to a table) until i realised that '5 seconds to go' meant more like 5 hours to go. so i balanced the external hard drive on my open laptop and began to juggle that along with my shopping bags home. it fell out of its socket and said 'try not to remove hard drive without clicking eject first'. I plugged it back in and now i have to start from zero. nothing was remembered. i just bet that time capsule

Comment: doesnt even securely hold onto my precious files if i delete them from my hard drive to free up space, which is the entire point! Oh my God! Carbon Copy Cloner costs money?!! Like I'm going to pay to drag my folders onto a second hard drive?!! GET ME OUT OF MACSVILLE! I cannot believe anyone can like a Mac. I face intense frustration with everything I do on it. From the selection highlight beginning at some arbritrary result in the list instead of at the top, to the 3.5GB of 3.5GB remaining of my 750GB failed Time capsule 'backup' to the fact you have to PAY MONEY for cutting and pasting files

Comment: If I wait another 12 hours and this tc thing actually finishes, would it be insane for me to format my internal hard drive and rely on the tc backup? if i plug it into a mac another day, will all my 750GB of original songs, manuscripts, scenes, edits and priceless recordings be gone as it tries to find space, shrugs and wipes everything to back up a 251GB hard drive from someone else's mac or something nuts like that? I need real life step by step instructions that are reasonable to answer the question in the header please. The guy who watered me down at the outset ripped the stakes out of it.

Comment: Paul, I'd be happy to help.  You obviously want someone to rant at.  I'm not that someone.  I'm sure you will find the perfect solution for you.

Comment: Anyone able to answer the basic question in the header? I dont want to pay to do it either.